# Inherited Web API API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a couple of classes

```
Square : Rectangle : Shape (abstract)
```

and I have a Base Controller inheriting from ApiController that I'd like to use.

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : ApiController where T : class
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> Get()
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class DerivedController : BaseController<Rectangle>
{
    public override IEnumerable<Rectangle> Get()
    ...
}

public class AnotherDerivedController : BaseController<Square>
{
    public new IEnumerable<Square> Get()
    ...
}
```

/api/rectangle will properly call `IEnumerable<Rectangle> Get()`

/api/square will give me an error:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Linq.IEnumerable`1[Square] Get() on type Web.Api.Controllers.AnotherDerivedController 
System.Linq.IEnumerable`1[Rectangle] Get() on type Web.Api.Controllers.DerivedController
```

If I change `public new IEnumerable<Square> Get()` to `public override IEnumerable<Square> Get()`, I get a compile time error since the return signatures are different

How do I get my code to call the proper method? Is it necessary to explicitly register each class's methods in RegisterRoutes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the Get, you are basically using it with `new`. This is not gonna work since the class will have two Get methods and Web API will be confused to pick which one.

You may define the `BaseController` as `abstract` and `Get` as `virtual` or `abstract` and then implement in your `DerivedController`.

Comment: Hi Aliostad, I updated my question to reflect your changes. I'm still getting some problems here, but your suggestions were helpful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have two controllers that can take your square class.  How are you registering your routes?  If you rename the controlers to rectangleController and SquareController you will probably be fine.

Comment: Right now, I just have the default route    `routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });` In my actual code, I do have (RectangleController) and (SquareController)... but it is still not routing correctly, giving me the same error message.